# Can't get URI of captured screenshot from intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)!

Tags: android, android-intent, screenshot, intentfilter

I'm trying to get the `URI` of just captured `screenshot` as I choose my app from `Open With` dialog. But I always get null from `intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)` in the provided code sample.

This is my `intent filter`:

Implemented two `intent-filter`s

First one: Makes my activity main and launcher.

Second one: Makes it an image viewer.(registers this activity on the system as an image viewer)

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

And this is how I'm trying to get the `URI` from the intent that invoked my activity.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
        Uri mediaUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        // Here mediaUri is always null 
    }
}
```

Comment: Uri value will be in data field, you need to use intent.getData().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `ACTION_VIEW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW):

> Input: getData() is URI from which to retrieve data.

So, change your code to:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
        Uri mediaUri = intent.getData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
        Uri mediaUri = (Uri)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        // Here mediaUri is always null 
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiler says: "casting `intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)` to `URI` is redundant". And I've tried it before with no luck.